# Foundation 5 dropdown align:left doesn't work in small screens

Tags: zurb-foundation

Here is the screenshot

[image]

I have a 500x400 iframe that hosts my page with a few Foundation dropdown controls, I found in this size no matter how I specify "align:xxx" value in the code, Foundation always renders the dropdown layer as align:bottom which is undesirable. I need "align:xxx" to work no matter what the containing page size is. How do I do that? Hacks or workarounds can do too.

I tried to increase my iframe to 1000x400 and the dropdown renders normally.

If there's an option that I could force align of a dropdown other than align:xxx please point out.

Answer (score 1):

It's because it's in an iframe that is smaller than the medium media query. The default behavior for the small breakpoint is to be 100% width. You may need JS to override this for your use case.

Comment: I found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25211054/foundation-5-change-direction-of-dropdown-with-jquery-for-small-to-medium-scre but it doesn't seem to work.